# How do I enter text into my DB record exactly as it was typed?

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I am developing a PHP website using MySQL. A function of the website allows users to enter a comment, just like Facebook. My SQL table stores the comment in a comment table with a title field (VARCHAR) and a content field (TEXT).

I want to be able to allow the users to type multiple paragraphs. For example:

Par 1.

Par 2.

But when I enter the record into the table it is saved as: Par 1 Par 2....  i.e it combines the two paragraphs together.

So what I do to retain paragraphs just like I am doing right now when I am typing this question into Stack Overflow?

Code for my text area is below. It's fairly basic.

```
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="Content"rows="5">    </textarea>
 </div>
```

And then to show that comment again

```
<div class="panel-body">
<p>
{{ $article->content }}
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatever data you send to the database will be stored as-is.  If you have code which is modifying your data, we can't know.

Comment: You will either need to parse the input before storing it in the database, adding `<br>` or `<p>` tags to the text, or you need to parse the raw text when fetching it, adding `<br>` or `<p>`-tags, or simply using things like `nl2br()` on the text.

Comment: *But when I enter the record into the table it is saved as: Par 1 Par 2.... i.e it combines the two paragraphs together.*, not unless you have combined them yourself. SQL won't trim newlines. Why do you think they are removed? What are you using to inspect the text after it's been stored?

Comment: `echo '<p>' .  $datrow['comment'] . '</p>';  `

Comment: Hi as David says put code please

Comment: If you're looking to have full paragraphs entered in on a comment box, the first thing I would do is change the comment field in your database to either "text" or "tinytext" as this would be better to storing a record that has more than 255 characters. VARCHAR only allows a max character value of 255. So you will run into another problem in the near future when storing a lengthy comment.

Comment: The part that stores the actual comment is already TEXT. Just the title is VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

When echoing the text out to the user use something like `nl2br()` that converts the newlines in the text to `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should use htmlentities to avoid XSS attacks.

```
nl2br(htmlentities($comment, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```